# Email to my friend

Tags: windows, windows-10

What do this figures mean in my email to my friend.  They were not there when I sent it to her, but when she opened the letter, there they were - as follows - \uD83E\uDD14

Answer (score 1):

The likely explanation is that you are using a different character encoding than
your friend.

For example, you may be sending special characters in another language to
someone who only uses English, and they are then displayed as binary
in hexadecimal.

I suggest to compare the email you sent with what she sees to find out which
are these characters.